# How pass a class instance from Form1 to UserControl correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, class, visual-studio-2017, user-controls

Hello I hope you can help me, I've been trying like more than 10 days to solve this problem.

I have a Form Application with 1 usercontrol and 1 Class and need use my class instance created in Form1 inside the UserControl1. (With Form1 to Form2 it's works fine)

Class CMensaje:

```
namespace WindowsFormsAppInstanciarClaseEnControl
{

public class CMensajes
{
    private string mensaje;

    public CMensajes()
    {

    }

    public string Mensaje { get => mensaje; set => mensaje = value; }
 }
}
```

UserControl1:

```
namespace WindowsFormsAppInstanciarClaseEnControl
{
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    CMensajes mensajito;

    public UserControl1(CMensajes mensa)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mensajito = mensa;
    }

    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = mensajito.Mensaje;
    }
  }
}
```

Form1

```
namespace WindowsFormsAppInstanciarClaseEnControl
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CMensajes mensajito = new CMensajes();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mensajito.Mensaje = textBox1.Text;
        UserControl1 usercontrol1 = new UserControl1(mensajito);

    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that it's works but intermediately I start to get

The variable `mensajito` is either undeclared or was never assigned. When I open `Form1 Design`. When I do the same code with `Form1` to `Form2` everything perfect!!

Really I need to pass a instance of my class `serialport` but is the same Here I write only a test code to understand what could I do?

Thanks.

[Error Screen when I try to open Form1.designer.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poPk7.jpg)

Comment: declare but can't instantiate this => CMensajes mensajito = new CMensajes(); inside class, need to be inside constructor or other method

Comment: @SonalBorkar: That is not right. You can declare and intantiate a field this way.

Comment: Is the user control shown in the form? If yes, it will be created  and loaded when the form loads. At this time no vlaue is assigned to `mensajito` and accessing it would cause an error.

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand. I instantiate in Form1 and inside UserControl1 only declare

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen yes the UserControl is shown in the Form1

Comment: But what should happen, when you click button1 in the form? Youwould instantiate a new usercontrol instance which is never used. `UserControl1 usercontrol1 = new UserControl1(mensajito);`

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen yes this is only a easy example to understand in my UserControl1 I only have a label1 and a button and when I clic button the label get the string correctly and it's working ok. But then when I open Form1.cs (Design)  it show me error The variable 'mensajito' is either undeclared or was never assigned. and I can't open the Design Form1.cs

Comment: Then the answer of Mark Parker should solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, instantiate the class mensajito inside the Form1 constructor, also add a form level field for the UserControl as you have with the class. Then in the button click event, check that the class is initialized,  if not, new it up, then initialize the usercontrol after assigning to the class property and then pass the class to the instance of the UC.

Comment: @MarkParker Thanks for your answer, after try and try all the night and like 10 days finally I could. I created a Get and Set Properties of my class CMensajes and now I can pass my instance directly without using the constructor. Thanks a lot. I didnt know.

Comment: No problem at all, more than happy to assist. Please remember to mark the answer as the accepted answer if this solved the problem so anyone else who visits this thread knows which answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me you should do this inside the User Control constructor:

```c#
public UserControl1(CMensajes mensa)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  mensajito = new CMensajes();
  mensajito = mensa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't got a machine in front of me to test this but at the risk of sounding silly,  try adding a default constructor to your user control.

```
public UserControl1()
{ 
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Or try moving the instantiation of your class inside the Form constructor.

Comment: Sorry It's the same error. I think I need the constructor to receive the class instance.

Comment: I've added the error screen in a link of my post. I've tried overload constructors. public UserControl1()   and public UserControl1(CMensaje mensa) the error dissapear but then the usercontrol not receive the class instance.